# MongoDB - replace item in nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

MongoDB [does not allow](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1050) to replace an item in an array in a single operation. Instead it's a pull followed by a push operation.

Unfortunately we have a case where we end up with a race condition on the same item in the array on parallel requests (distributed environment), i.e. 
2x pull runs first, then 2x push. This results in duplicate entries, e.g.

```
{
    "_id": ...,
    "nestedArray": [
        {
            "subId": "1"
        },
        {
            "subId": "1"
        },
        {
            "subId": "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use an optimistic lock for this situation.
To prepare for this, you need to add a version field to your model, which you will increment each time you modify that model. Then you use this method:

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate(
        {$and: [{_id: <current_id>}, {version: <current_version>}]}, 
        {nestedArray: <new_nested_array>})
  .exec(function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
      // handle error
    }
    if(!result) {
      // the model has been updated in the mean time
    }
    // all is good
});
```

This means that you first need to get the model and compute the new array `<new_nested_array>`. This way you can be sure that only one modification will take place for a certain version.
Hope I explained myself.

Comment: I guess that's why MongoDB still gets hate from the SQL camp... :) Came up with such a solution before but it felt not right. Thanks

Comment: You need to change your whole approach to work with MongoDB. I don't know your requirements, but maybe try to investigate Redis, which can be used in conjunction with MongoDB and supports transactions.